# Mule EE jars vs CE jars

Tags: mule

We are using mule (enterprise edition) and are debating whether to use EE jars (whenever available) or CE jars. Is there a reason to go one way or another. The application is eventually going to deployed in Mule Enterprise edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the EE jars in order to have the EE versions of the XML schemas to resolve properly.

Comment: David ... Can you explain it a little more. We have some applications that use mule-core as dependency whereas others which are using mule-core-ee as dependency. All the applications use standard features available in community edition (as of now). It seems both types of applications are currently working fine. Under what conditions will the applications having ce jars can have schema-resolving-problems?

Comment: If you use `jdbc-ee` features for example.